# Store image in new directory in PHP

Tags: php, android

so i can upload my photo from my Android app fine to **/var/www/html/ProductPhotos** but when i want to get the name of the Product and use that as the name of the new directory and image name then its not working. I create the new directory and **/var/www/html/ProductPhotos** with 777 permissions (even though its super bad) but for now its what i need. here's my PHP code:

```
<?php


    $ProductAccountName = $_POST['ProductAccountName'];
    $ProductName = $_POST['ProductName'];
    $ProductImage = $_POST['EncodedImage'];

    $NewDirectory = "/var/www/html/ProductPhotos/" . $ProductAccountName;
    mkdir($NewDirectory, 0777, true);

    //$DecodedProductImage = base64_decode("$ProductImage");
    //$ProductName = $ProductName .".JPG";

    file_put_contents("/var/www/html/ProductPhotos/" . $ProductAccountName, $ProductName . ".JPG", $DecodedProductImage);

?>
```

Comment: That worked! thank you! also put it as the answer so i can give you credit

Comment: done + added my 2 cents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a comma instead of a period. And you're missing a slash.

```
file_put_contents("/var/www/html/ProductPhotos/" . $ProductAccountName . "/" . $ProductName . ".JPG", $DecodedProductImage);`
```

See the [file_put_contents docs.](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

You may want to be  put into place some checks to make sure the user doesn't use relative paths(using ../ as part the ProductAccountName, for example). Just be careful of the user using this to do malicious things.